# How to create full height content section with fixed header and footer in CSS with scrollbar hidden if not required

Tags: html, css

There are loads of questions like this on stackoverflow but none did exactly what I wanted.
My requirements:

- Fixed Header and footer
- content section that takes up 100% of the space between the header and footer even when little or no content
- content section does not go under the footer unless it is too big and scrollbars required
- scroll bars hidden when content fits properly in between the header and footer

The question is how do I implement this without any JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that you can use:

HTML:

```
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='content'></div>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
#header{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
#content{
 position: fixed;
 top: 100px;
 bottom: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
 overflow: auto;
}
#footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Look here at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4n0txxp/2/)

Comment: That doesn't scroll at all when the content is too big. Other than that a nice solution if you just set the overflow to auto

Comment: Oh, I thought that you didn't want to scroll, updated...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle with my solution that does everything that I want:

https://jsfiddle.net/46vs3bfe/

We set the header and footer to have a height of 50 pixels.

```
#header,
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

We then set the margin top and bottom for the content section to be 55 (or 50 if you don't want a gap:

```
#content {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This however will not make the content section 100% of the height if there is not enough content. If there was a background to this div it would only take up a small amount of the space between the header and footer if there was not much content.
One way of fixing this is by setting the height of the content:

```
min-height: 100%
```

This means that the content section will always be at the minimum the same height as the whole page. The problem with this is that as the content section starts 55 pixels down the page the bottom is ALWAYS off the bottom of the page. This means that we get a scroll bar even if the page is mostly empty. To fix this we need to calculate the height of the content section to be 100% minus the total height of the header and footer:

```
min-height: calc(100% - 110px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **[this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0jv1hujk/)**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: 'auto';
  padding: 100px 0;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='content'>
  <br>1 START
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2
  <br>1
  <br>2END
</div>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

Comment: Please explain and add the relevant code to your answer, not just a JSFiddle link to it.